How to get the location of the page object referenced by the PDF outline in Python

When I click on an item in the outlines on the left, the software jumps to the position of the arrow on the right, so I wonder if I can use python to get this position so that I can crop the PDF.
This is my code.
import fitz

file = 'assets/xxx.pdf'
pdf = fitz.open(file)
outlines = pdf.get_toc(simple=False)
xref = outlines[13][3]['xref']  # choose a outline
t_xref = int(pdf.xref_get_key(xref, 'A')[1].split()[0])
print(pdf.xref_object(t_xref))

and this is output
<<\n  /D [ 391 0 R /FitH 456 ]\n  /S /GoTo\n>>

But don't know how to convert the FitH parameters into positions or coordinates on the page.
My English is poor, the above content is translated with the help of Google :)
Get a coordinate value or just a height value.

I'll try to explain this so you can easily understand!
Get the outline entry’s page number and /FitH value, where /FitH is the y-coordinate for the top view position. Then use the page number to load the correct page in PyMuPDF.
Define a rectangle (Rect) from the /FitH y-coordinate to the bottom of the page and then you can use this rectangle as the crop area, so only the section from the /FitH position downward is visible.

Each item in outlines has a destination dictionary as last subitem. If the destination is internal (points to a place in this PDF) then you will find the dict key "to", which is a point, and a 0-based "page" page number. You don't need to bother yourself with PDF's cryptic codes like /Fit and what not else.

... and BTW the destination is not a "PDF object"! It only is a combination of page number and a point location on that page.
